# How to identify V-in V-out pins on Lineage Regulator?

Tags: voltage, linear-regulator

I botched a soldering job and burned off the V-In pin of a micro FPV camera circuit. Luckily, I identified a lineage regulator next to it, which I see has a V-in pin from schematics of similar lineage regulators. Since I couldn't find the exact part online I was wondering if you could help me identify the v-in pin.

From testing continuity, I figured out that pin 2 is ground. That leaves 2 other pins, assuming v-in is on the side with 3 pins. I am inclined to say that v-in is the pin closest to where the V-in terminal of the circuit board used to be (pin 1) but can't be sure. Is there a way to identify v-in ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some assumptions: You likely have a higher voltage input to the board, and a lower voltage to that other IC on the board.

Find continuity between one of those regulator pins and where ever power comes into the PCB, and you will have your input pin.

Find continuity between the regulator and any pin from the other IC that is not ground. That should be the output pin.

There is not enough information in the post for a more definitive answer, so this is just the best guess.

Comment: thank you! luckily a little bit of copper survived the gun and I traced it to pin 1